# Update column depending on other column by calculation

Tags: mysql

seems like a stupid question...

I have a mysql table where I want to modify column A to a number 0 or 1 depending on the condition of another column B

So: if( B > 500 ) A = 1 ELSE A = 0

Column A = INT
Column B = DOUBLE

How do you do something like this in sql?

Thanks,

Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following statement,

```
UPDATE tableName
SET A = (B > 500)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8a68/1)

`(B > 500)` is a boolean arithmetic in mysql which returns `1` and `0` for `true` and `false` , respectively.

You can also use `CASE` for much more RDBMS friendly,

```
UPDATE tableName
SET A = CASE WHEN B > 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```